# Sails.js query for waterline association

Tags: sails.js, waterline

In sails.js I've a Post model with a many-to-many association with another model called "tag"

POSTS MODEL

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
      title:        'string',
      content:      'string',
      coverImage:   'string',
      owner: {
          model: 'user'
      },
      tags: {
          collection: 'ContentTag',
                 via: 'posts',
            dominant: true // ---
      }
    }

};
```

TAGS MODEL

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
      name: 'string',
      posts: {
          collection: 'post',
          via: 'tags'
      }
  }
};
```

Now I want to get the related Posts with the same tags. I've try to play around with .populate('tags') and and .populate('tags',{name: ['tag1','tag2']) but I can't figure out how to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse your query

`Tags.find({name:['tag1','tag2']}).populate('posts')`

Comment: Yes I've tried bus the result is a set of tag with relative posts, not only a set of posts. So I've to parse all results in order to consolidate.... Very inefficient.

Comment: Inefficient yes. But the most efficient way currently is with Native / Query methods. If you want to use waterline then you would have to do something like ```Tags.find({name:['tag1','tag2']}).populate('posts').exec(function(err,tagsWPosts){posts = tagsWPosts.map(function(tag){if(tag.posts.length>0)return posts})})``` However, this issue is being worked on and should be solved by the next version of waterline I believe.

Comment: Hi Meeker, I know about the feature request in waterline but, as we don't know when will be released, I think that I'll will try to implement your solution. Thanks for help me, your javascript is definitely stronger that mine :)

Comment: Another solution would be to create a method in your Posts model that returns posts in a less efficient way, then you can replace that code in on spot easily when the feature is released.